# Unit Test for certain types of exceptions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception

Some background before I get into my question. I am currently working on a project that is migrating from an IBM DB2 to a SQL Server. Not to get into too much detail, but this DB2 linked server sometimes disconnects with the SQL server, which is normal for linked servers. I have this working in code and have a process setup for this to take care of it.

Anyway, I am trying to write a Test Method that throws a DbException (which is the exception that is thrown when the linked server is not connected) to test the process which I wrote when the linked server is disconnected. Is there a way to force throw a certain type of exception so I can test my code?

The try catch block looks something like this:

```
try
{
    //Regular Processing and attempt to update to DB2
}
catch (DbException ex)
{
    //Other processing to catch a linked server issue
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    //Even more processing for other exceptions
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same method as most unit testing, Inject your dependency via an interface, put your real db logic in one class based on that interface, and your 
test stuff in another based on that interface.

```
interface  IDBProcessor
{
   void Process()
}

class ThrowyClass : IDBProcessor
{
    public Exception ThrowThis {get; set;}
    public void Process() 
    {
        throw ThrowThis;
    }
}


void MyMethod(IDBProcessor processor)
{
  try
  {
    processor.Process()
  }
  catch (DbException ex)
  {
    //Other processing to catch a linked server issue
  }
  catch (Exception ex) 
  {
    //Even more processing for other exceptions
  }
}
```

Then in your unit test,  Make a ThrowyClass with the exception you want and pass it in. ( There are mocking frameworks that will save you from making a Test class if you like).

```
[Test]
void MyThrowTest()
{
   var throwy = new ThrowyClass() { ThrowThis = new SomeSpecificException() };
   var myClass = new MyClass()
   myClass.MyMethod(throwy);
   // Assert what you expect
}
```

You will have to customize things to your specific application.  You may wish to inject the IProcessor in the constructor of "MyClass"

Answer (score 0):

You can simply throw it like this way :

```
throw new DbException();
```

Comment: `DbException` is an abstract class. You have to either create a custom exception class that can derive from it, then throw your custom class, or throw any existing type that derives from `DbException` like `SqlException`.

Comment: You are right, I tought it was just an ordinary class which inherits from Exception class

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `IDbConnection` and try the `Moq` framework
your code should like the following

```
var dbConnectionMock = new Mock<IDbConnection>();
dbConnectionMock.Setup(x => x.Open())
                   .Callback(() => {
                           throw new SqlException();
                       }).Verifiable();
```

https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart